# using FontIcon Glyph from code (C#)

Tags: c#, icons, win-universal-app

I try to add some of the base provided icon from FontIcon class for universal windows 10 apps (those that we can see mostly in appbar). when running this piece of code, it run without any problem, but in fact, it shows some border square, such as non recognized emoticon character.

```
Button infoButton = new Button();
infoButton.Content = new FontIcon
{
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets"),
    Glyph = "&#xE946;",
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke)
};
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is the problem how XAML and C# deal with the Unicode Characters. When you use this in XAML code, it is something like `Glyph = "&#xE946;"`, but when you use this in the C# code, it should be like this: `Glyph = "\uE946"`.

There is no specific document for this details, but some cases on MSDN & SO forum have the same implementation: [AppBarButton.Icon doesn't change on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069541/appbarbutton-icon-doesnt-change-on-runtime).

In C# code behind, we need to use the escape character.

Comment: @Grace Feng, I'm trying to use custom font as mentioned in the question on server side. This works if I install my fonts though I just want to reference custom font without installing. Any tips?

Comment: I found one sample that uses the following " Glyph = "" i am not sure how it will show to you but i see it as a rectangle with question mark in the middle and here only a rectangle. I updated it as you mentioned and it's working fine but what's up with this? do i need a plugin or something to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Or in XAML:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <FontIcon 
            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
            Glyph="&#xE946;"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Couldn't do this by XAML because it is generated from a server